# BNF ambiguities

Tags: compiler-construction, bnf

"Compiler construction" book  gives an example of the original definition of Algol 60. They contain ambiguities.

Find at least two different structures for

```
IF a THEN b ELSE c=d
```

There is part of definition

```
unconditional Statement = basicStatement | forStatement | compoundStatement | ... .
ifStatement = "IF" BooleanExpression "THEN" unconditionalStatement.
conditionalStatement = ifStatement | ifStatement "ELSE" statement.

statement = unconditionalStatement | conditionalStatement.
```

so then, since:

```
A "else" B, and A => "if" a "then" b
```

we gets:

```
if a then b else B
```

and it seems, `B` is `c=d`

Where is ambiguities?
How to find two different structures?

Comment: Are you sure you are quoting this correctly? Like you, I don't see the ambiguity here, but this question reminds me of the [dangling else](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

Comment: me too, maybe its the answer; then how to add the brackets in BNF?

Comment: There is no "dangling else" issue here. The `else` is present and must be present because conditional expressions require "else" clauses; thus, conditional *expressions* -- as opposed to conditional statements -- don't exhibit the "dangling else" ambiguity.

Comment: Many thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IF a THEN b ELSE c=d` is not a statement. It's an expression of some kind; what kind it is depends on the type of `b`. (The statement would be `IF a THEN b ELSE c:=d.` Recall that in Algol, `:=` is assignment, `=` is equality comparison, and `==` is a syntax error.)

If `b` is a boolean, then it is a boolean conditional expression whose alternatives are `b` and `c=d`; in this case, `c` and `d` must have arithmetic type because the grammar doesn't allow comparing booleans with `=`.

But if `b` is arithmetic, then it is a comparison between the arithemtic conditional expression `IF a THEN b ELSE c` and `d` (and, again, `c` and `d` must have arithmetic type).

At least, that's my reading of the grammar. It's not exactly ambiguous, but the BNF is not sufficient to resolve the parse because the language is not context-free. Selecting the correct parse requires the previous declaration of `b`, which can only be achieved with a context-sensitive grammar.